# WebStorm: 2nd project window gets opened BEHIND 1st project window

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I often work with multiple projects open at a time.  If I already have a project open and I go to open another existing project, the newly-opened project window will open ***behind*** the project window I was just working on.  In other words, the new window does not become active.  It's extremely annoying and has led to repo mistakes on multiple occasions.

Is this the normal/intended behavior and if so, can it be changed to force the newly-opened project to become the active window?

- WebStorm 2017.2.4
- Win7 x64

Comment: This question (and it's answers) are [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358347/why-was-my-answer-not-accepted-when-it-came-first-and-is-almost-identical-to-th#358390), which may cause some voting irregularities due to it's increased visibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Opening other project in foreground is normal behavior.
More likely you have faced a bug. It's already reported on the JetBrains bugtracker and not fixed yet. [Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167068) its status, you can check there if somebody has found some workaround, vote up and subscribe for notifications.